# Python requests downloading big files in slower speed than wget

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, network-file-transfer, python-requests

This is a simple toy downloader using python's `requests` library.

I’ve monitored the download process is slower on an ethernet connected box. The realtime speed is measured both on `stdout`, using `get_net_speed()` function, and `conky`.

I’m using a 4Mbps connection.

When downloading a file using `wget`, the downloading gets full bandwidth as expected. But when using my own `downloader` script, it gets highest 1Mbps speed.

Here's the code. Review and optimisation are warmly welcome.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

### get details of a requested file and download if a media one 


import requests
import sys
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import socket
import re 
import time
import psutil 

#===================== Main Routine ===================================



def down_in_chunks(resp,file_name,conSize):
    downloaded = 0
    file_descriptor = open(file_name,'wb')
    chunk_size = 1024 * 1024 # 1MB
    for chunk in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
        downloaded += int(len(chunk)) # get update how much downloaded
        per_cent = 100 * downloaded / int(conSize)
        speed = get_net_speed()
        print("downloading %.2f pc speed %s" %(per_cent,speed),end='\r')
        file_descriptor.write(chunk)
    file_descriptor.close()

#================== Auxilary Routines ==================================

def get_net_speed():
    rcv = psutil.net_io_counters()
    sp0 = rcv[1]
    time.sleep(1)
    rcv = psutil.net_io_counters()
    sp1 = rcv[1]
    speed = sp1 - sp0 
    return convert_size(speed)

def convert_size(file_size):
    for unit in ["B","KiB","MiB","GiB","Tib","PiB","EiB","Zib"]:
        if abs(file_size) <= 1024.0 or abs(file_size) == 0:
            return "%3.1f%s" %(file_size,unit) 
        else:
            file_size /= 1024.0
        #return "%3.1f%s" %(file_size,unit) 


def get_file_details(resp,url):

    file_type = resp.headers["Content-Type"]

    if re.match(r'^html|text',file_type): # perhaps we're not interested in the page only 
        print("header info... ", resp.headers)

    else:
        file_name = url.split("/")[-1]
        print("file name: %s" % file_name)
        conDate = resp.headers["Date"]
        conType = resp.headers["Content-Type"]
        conTn = resp.headers["Connection"]
        conSize = resp.headers["Content-Length"]
        conUnit = resp.headers["Accept-Ranges"]
        humane = convert_size(int(conSize))
        print("time: %s type: %s size: %s (%s) unit: %s connection: %s " %(conDate,conType,conSize,humane,conUnit,conTn))
        return file_name , conSize

# ========== Action ===========

try:

    url = sys.argv[1] # get the url
    urlObj = urlparse(url)
    addr = urlObj.netloc
    ip = socket.gethostbyname(addr.split(":")[0]) # get the ip address
    print("connecting to %s | %s |... " %(addr,ip))
    user_agent = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; hu-HU; rv:1.7.8) Gecko/20050511 Firefox/1.0.4'}
    resp = requests.get(sys.argv[1],stream=True,timeout=15,headers=user_agent) # I'm not a bot Maa'm
    print("status: %s " %(resp.status_code))
    file_name,file_size = get_file_details(resp,url)

    print("downloading.......... %s" %file_name)
    start = time.time()
    down_in_chunks(resp,file_name,file_size)
    end = time.time()
    total_time = end - start
    if total_time >= 60:
        print("download time: %.2f min" %(total_time/60))

    else:
        print("download time: %.2f secs")
    resp.close()


except requests.exceptions.RequestException as E:
    print("Error: ", E)
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: How is `get_net_speed` measuring the download speed when it pauses the download?

Comment: Nice point. But needs a concreted explanation

Answer (score 2):

By using `time.sleep(1)` on `get_net_speed` you are limiting your download speed to the block size per second, since your block has 1MB you are limited to 1Mbps.

Comment: 1MB / s is different from 1Mb / s (i.e. 1Mbps).

Comment: @GZ0 My guess is that it's being rounded down

Comment: It is very unlikely that 1MB / s = 8Mbps is rounded down to 1Mbps.